# Protractor hover mouse over X Y coordinates on SVG pie chart and return tool tip value

Tags: protractor, webdriverjs

I'm from WebDriver+Java background and new to Protractor, WebDriverJS and Jasmine. I have a page object and there I'm trying to define a function that will hover over a pie chart on a given X Y coordinates and get the tool tip value and return it back to the calling function. But so far no luck. Can anyone please help me to find a better solution for this?

```
this.getDisCount = function() {
    var dis = element(by
            .css('#piecontainer .highcharts-series>path[fill="#434348"]'));
    return dis.getSize().then(function(size) {
        return (size['height'] / 2).then(function(value) {
            return browser.actions().mouseMove(dis, {
                x : value,
                y : 0
            }).perform().then(function() {
                return element(by.css('#piecontainer g.highcharts-tooltip tspan:nth-of-type(6)')).getText().then(function(text) {
                    return text;
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Getting the following exception with the above code.

- Failed: (size.height / 2).then is not a function
    at D:\workspace\eclipse\IotTester\page\UseCase1\HomePage.js:85:32
    at D:\workspace\eclipse\IotTester\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js
  :697:28

Comment: well, you need to use then on something which returns a promise. When promise is successfully resolved, it goes in to 'then' section. You can create a function which calculates size['height']/2 for you and then can call that function here. this way you can use then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problematic part is on this line:

```
return (size['height'] / 2).then(function(value) {
```

The `size` is an already resolved size object, it is not a promise, the `then()` part is not needed.

Also, let the `getDisCount()` function return the `getText()` promise:

```
this.getDisCount = function() {
    var dis = element(by.css('#piecontainer .highcharts-series>path[fill="#434348"]'));
    dis.getSize().then(function(size) {
        return browser.actions().mouseMove(dis, {
            x : size['height'] / 2,
            y : 0
        }).perform();
    });

    return element(by.css('#piecontainer g.highcharts-tooltip tspan:nth-of-type(6)')).getText();
}
```

Then, once you need the value, resolve the result of the function:

```
myPageObject.getDisCount().then(function (discountValue) {
    console.log(discountValue);
});
```

Comment: However still the x : size['height'] / 2 seems not working. If I put a logger it returns 83. If I hard code the value  x : 83 it works. Cant figure why  x : size['height'] / 2, is not working

Comment: It finally worked. I used the following to resolve it x : parseInt((size['width'] / 2).toFixed(0))

Comment: I am not able to find the element for this SVG - https://gist.github.com/rohitkadam19/452c96d9c2bd9538e2f0111de8b93953 Could you please help? @alecxe

Comment: @alecxe XPath I am trying is - `element(by.xpath("//donut-chart/svg/g/path[@fill='#CE4B99']"))`

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with protractor instance, so try the selenium instance of web driver that can be obtained using `browser.driver` and use the `dragAndDrop` method for the element which you want to hover.

```
await browser.driver.actions()
    .dragAndDrop(elementToHover, elementToHover)
    .perform();
```